# How to correctly define if gevent functionality is available?

Tags: python, gevent

I'm implementing reusable python module which makes use of gevent for async http requests. If gevent is not available then we fall back to sync requests. Now I ended up with:

```
_use_gevent = False

try:
    import gevent
    # gevent 1.0bN renamed coros to lock
    try:
        from gevent.lock import Semaphore
    except ImportError:
        from gevent.coros import Semaphore
    # Verify gevent has patched os. If not we just don't use gevent.
    import os
    if 'gevent' in os.fork.__module__:
        _use_gevent = True
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Is this correct way to define if gevent is available and its patches actually applied?

Comment: I think it's more typical to just count on the user to specify whether to use gevent as a command-line option or the like, but if you do want to do auto-detection, I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could check `sys.modules['gevent']`.

Also you could check `gevent.__version__` to figure if you have to import gevent.lock or gevent.coros.